# Force non-empty MAIL FROM for outgoing email

Tags: php, postfix, smtp, sendmail

I am using postfix on a Debian server, primarily to send outgoing email for websites and notifications, and have run into an issue where outgoing email to a certain mailing list provider is rejected but email to "normal" individual email addresses goes through just fine.

I've been informed this is due to an empty MAIL FROM, since that typically indicates a bounce or a spammer, which mailing lists don't accept. However, this isn't a bounce - it's the initial outgoing message. However, it does seem if I debug the SMTP session, MAIL FROM is empty:

```
May 14 12:41:49 mail postfix/smtp[13274]: > REDACTED[REDACTED]:25: MAIL FROM:<>
May 14 12:41:49 mail postfix/smtp[13274]: smtp_stream_setup: maxtime=300 enable_deadline=0
May 14 12:41:49 mail postfix/smtp[13274]: < REDACTED[REDACTED]:25: 250 2.0.0 OK
May 14 12:41:49 mail postfix/smtp[13274]: > REDACTED[REDACTED]:25: RCPT TO:<redacted@example.com>
May 14 12:41:49 mail postfix/smtp[13274]: smtp_stream_setup: maxtime=300 enable_deadline=0
May 14 12:41:49 mail postfix/smtp[13274]: < REDACTED[REDACTED]:25: 500 Bad bounce
```

The mail itself is queued locally on the same sever using the `mail` function in PHP. It contains both `From` and `Sender` headers.

I don't know why postfix isn't sending a MAIL FROM, but I suspect it could be due to this other reason:

> almost all bounce messages use this as well as certain other circumstances, **to indicate they do not wish to receive a bounce message in the event of a delivery error**

https://lists.debian.org/debian-isp/2004/01/msg00259.html

However, in this case, indicating that it doesn't want a bounce is breaking outgoing email to certain destinations that *require* a non-empty MAIL FROM.

How can I force it to send a MAIL FROM, such as from a specific address if necessary?

Comment: What is your PHP configuration `sendmail_path` and `mail.force_extra_parameters` set to? (calling `phpinfo()` will dump configuration)

Comment: @anx /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i and empty